# Angular2 *ngFor loop getting height of each loop (Only gets first one)

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a ngFor loop like so: `<div  *ngFor="let group of catt" id="juliet" [ngClass]="hf()">` where I call the hf() function each time which looks like so:

```
hf() {
    this.heighty = document.getElementById('juliet').offsetHeight;
    console.log("juliet function height = " + this.heighty);

  }
```

But the for loop goes through 4 times for the data, but only gives the height of the first loop, and then gives that same height for each loop their after. When I inspect the elements I see the 4 loops with different heights. I also do not see an identifier for each loop, like `juliet[0]`. How do I get the heights for each loop of the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `id` as it will be repeating that DOM multiple times(though `document.getElementById('juliet')` will first instance of element) on the page, instead use template variable like `#juliet` shown below.

```
<div *ngFor="let group of catt" #juliet [ngClass]="hf(juliet)">
```

And then calculate height of each DOM by passing `juliet` in `hf` method.

```
hf(element) {
    this.heighty = element.offsetHeight;
   console.log("juliet function height = " + this.heighty);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the CLEAR answer, and it works excellently!